# Elasticsearch Nest and CopyTo

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Has anyone located or used a CopyTo attribute in Nest?  I can see it's been added as part of the fluent mapping but can't seem to find it as an attribute which is how I am carrying out all my mapping currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute-based mapping in NEST doesn't support `CopyTo`.  You need to use the fluent API.  See my comment [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/949) for an explanation.