# Combining Attribute / Fluent Mapping for Copy_To with Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to use the copy_to functionality with Nest. I've read that I need to use the fluent mapping ([Elasticsearch Nest and CopyTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873551/elasticsearch-nest-and-copyto)).

Is it possible to use the attribute based mapping then fluent mapping on top of that to add copy_to? If so, are there any examples? I'm having difficulty finding the answer.

The field I want to copy to does not exist in my model class. I just want to search on it in elasticsearch.

```
[ElasticType(IdProperty = "CustomerId", Name = "customer_search")]
public class CustomerSearchResult : BindableBase
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "customer_id", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "account_type", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "short_name", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "legacy_name", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string LegacyName { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "legacy_contact_name", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string LegacyContactName { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "city", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "state_abbreviation", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string StateAbbreviation { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "country", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "postal_code", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

In the above class I want to use ShortName, LegacyName, and LegacyContactName and copy_to a field called "search" which will be an analyzed field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should do it

```
void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connection = new InMemoryConnection(settings);
    var client = new ElasticClient(connection: connection);


    var indexResponse = client.CreateIndex("customer_searches", c => c
        .AddMapping<CustomerSearchResult>(m => m
            .MapFromAttributes()
            .Properties(p => p
                .String(s => s.Name("short_name").CopyTo("search").Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                .String(s => s.Name("legacy_name").CopyTo("search").Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                .String(s => s.Name("legacy_contact_name").CopyTo("search").Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                .String(s => s.Name("search").Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed))
            )
        )
    );

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(indexResponse.RequestInformation.Request));
}
```

Which outputs

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {}
  },
  "mappings": {
    "customer_search": {
      "properties": {
        "customer_id": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "account_type": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "short_name": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "copy_to": [
            "search"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "legacy_name": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "copy_to": [
            "search"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "legacy_contact_name": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "copy_to": [
            "search"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state_abbreviation": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "country": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "postal_code": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "search": {
          "index": "analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The call to `Properties()` overrides the default conventions and attribute mappings so you need to specify that the fields are `not_analyzed` there as well.

Comment: What about Nest 2? Is there a way to do this from the attributes mapping decorators?

Comment: A lot of properties are exposed via mapping attributes but not all; generally, where a mapping property has more than property of its own e.g. `Norms` (can be enabled/disabled and lazy/eager loaded), it would only be settable via the fluent mapping api. Similarly, multi-fields can only be defined via fluent mapping. The attribute properties in NEST 2.x are for the most part similar to those available in NEST 1.x, generally differing where there have been changes in Elasticsearch. Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html